# Facebook and Mint Badges seem to be ignoring iOS 4 Notifications Settings

Tags: iphone, facebook

I have Badges turned off for the Facebook and Mint applications on my iPhone 4 running 4.0.2 (Settings -> Notifications -> Facebook/Mint -> Badges: OFF ). I have Alerts and Sounds turned on.

Despite the fact that badges are turned off, my Facebook and Mint applications continue to show red numerical badges on their icons.

I'd like to turn these badges off. Why are they continuing to show?

Comment: Since changing your settings did you get any new badges? Perhaps they are old alerts that just haven't cleared.

Answer (score 1):

The Notifications settings panel only controls what push notifications can do when the app is not running.  Background changing of the badge, essentially.  When you run the app, it is free to change its own badge and as far as I know there isn't a way to keep an app from doing that.

Answer (score 1):

The application has to provide a way to turn off/on badges.  Some apps provide that through the notifications setting, some in their own app settings (under Settings), and some within the app itself and some not at all.  The Facebook app does not seem to abide by the Notifications settings, so that request would need to be made to them to update their app to allow us to turn off badges if we so choose.